# IPhone two fingers twist gesture

Tags: iphone, gestures

I need to rotate an image when the user do a two finger twist on it.
do you have an idea on how i can code this or if you've done this before.

I think it would be a good idea to write a class that detect all the main gesture and provide iif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this example on the internet. It's very nicely written...

http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/08/multitouchsingletouchtap-handling/

Comment: This is one of the reasons why link only answers are discouraged, [but](http://web.archive.org/web/20110417162113/http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/08/08/multitouchsingletouchtap-handling/).

Answer (score -1):

When you rotate your thumb and index clockwise what really happens is that:

- the thumb starts on the right
- descrives a `u` shape underneath the index
- finishes on the left

If you look at the full gesture it is `.)` rotated clockwise. In some cases, the index will move slightly south-east so you get `/)`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest looking into SDK 3.2 - it has extended support for gesture detection.