# Turnable UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm looking for some pointers on how to create a turnable button like the knobs in garageband (iPad). I want to use this for a custom volume knob.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:
[IPhone two fingers twist gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442964/iphone-two-fingers-twist-gesture) ?

Comment: I'd utilize a combination of this and a `UIImageView` that rotates by leveraging the image view's `transform` property and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late, may be you have already found the answer! but I made this knob after getting inspired by garage band. Hopefully it will help you or any new members.

[image]

https://github.com/Krutarth/KnobGarageBandStyle

Enjoy!